# How to find and replace in the bookmarked lines in Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a problem about how to find and replace in the bookmarked lines in Notepad++.

For example my line is `<content:encode><em>....`

So I bookmark the lines that have `<content:encode>`, how I could find and replace `<em>` in those lines?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but there are a few options under **Search → Bookmark** which may be helpful. (`Copy Bookmarked Lines`, `Paste to (Replace) Bookmarked Lines`, `Remove Unmarked Lines`)

Comment: Do you want to replace <em> in all lines that contain <content:encode>?

Answer (score -4):

You can use regular expressions in find/replace in notepad++ so that you use the pattern that is found in your replacement.
You can find out exactly which regular expression you want here "http://www.powercram.com/2009/08/notepad-guide-to-using-regular.html"

Comment: You did not answer the OP's question.....he wants to only do replacement on the lines with bookmarks